# unable to create chain query in sql

Tags: sql

Assume I have the following tables in sql.

```
student 
name   id
alex   1
felix  2
hannah 3
john   4 
jonas  5


instructor  
name   id
alex   1
felix  2
hannah 3
john   4 
jonas  5
(ex)brad   8
tom    9
tonny  11

instructor_lectures
name   id   course_count
alex   1    5
felix  2    2
hannah 3    0
john   4    23
jonas  5    12
(ex)brad   8    1
tom    9    11
tonny  11   9
```

What I want to do is;

```
- firstly, get the difference of instructor student tables according to the name which does not start with "(ex)"
- and then list course_count of the result.
```

I mean, first get

```
name   id
tom    9
tonny  11
```

and then

```
name   id   course_count
tom    9    11
tonny  11   9
```

what have I done so far?

I have written the difference query and select query from instructor_lectures but couldn't combine them together.

```
SELECT NAME FROM instructor INSTR WHERE NOT EXISTS 
(
    SELECT * FROM student STU WHER INSTR.NAME = STU.NAME
) 
AND INSTR.NAME NOT REGEXP '^(ex)'
```

This query returns me

```
name   id
tom    9
tonny  11
```

Now I want to get the course_count by looking table instructor_lectures

```
SELECT NAME FROM instructor INSTR WHERE NOT EXISTS 
(
    SELECT * FROM student STU WHER INSTR.NAME = STU.NAME
) 
AND INSTR.NAME NOT REGEXP '^(ex)'
SELECT * FROM instructor_lectures INSTR_LECTURES WHERE INSTR.NAME = INSTR_LECTURES.NAME
```

but this throws error. Where is my mistake? How can I get the course_count of the result of the first difference query?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT INSTR.NAME, INSTR.id, INSTR_LECTURES.COURSE_COUNT
  FROM instructor INSTR, instructor_lectures INSTR_LECTURES
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM student STU WHER INSTR.NAME = STU.NAME)
   AND INSTR.NAME NOT REGEXP '^(ex)'
   and INSTR.NAME = INSTR_LECTURES.NAME
```

use a join condition, for info on [joins](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/queries006.htm#SQLRF52338)